# Kubernetes master node is not receiving internal IP

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I have followed the official guides and started a simple 3 node cluster, however
the command `kubeadm get nodes -o wide` prints this result:

```
NAME    STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP  
node2   Ready    master   12h   v1.13.4   <none>
node3   Ready    <none>   12h   v1.13.4   192.168.1.47 
node4   Ready    <none>   12h   v1.13.4   192.168.1.48
```

Please not the **INTERNAL-IP** of node2 (which is **master** node).

Because of that, pods that are on node2 do not receive an IP, even though all of them are system pods.

**Environment**:

1. Network: VirtualBox **bridged** adabter no NAT whatsoever
2. Network plugin: **Flannel**
3. OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

**Update**

Here is the output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` as requested in comments:

```
NAME                            STATUS          IP             NODE 
coredns-86c58d9df4-d2dv7        Running      10.244.0.52    node2
coredns-86c58d9df4-zwmzg        Running      10.244.0.51    node2
etcd-node2                      Running      <none>         node2
kube-apiserver-node2            Running      <none>         node2
kube-controller-manr-node2      Running      <none>         node2
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-5dpr9     Running      192.168.1.47   node3
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-97h5q     Running      <none>         node2
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-zwlxh     Running      192.168.1.48   node4
kube-proxy-4qlpc                Running      <none>         node2
kube-proxy-c28q9                Running      192.168.1.48   node4
kube-proxy-ntdxj                Running      192.168.1.47   node3
kube-scheduler-node2            Running      <none>         node2
```

pods on master are also getting `<none>`.

Also i have created a gist for `kubectl describe node node2` [here](https://gist.github.com/csafg2/4680a6a2a1dacb14b38def9596736da1)

Comment: share the output from kubectl get po -n kube-system

Comment: also please share `kubectl describe node node2` output

Comment: Added pods and node info.

Comment: Do you see any IP related errors with `journalctl -u kubelet -f -l` ?

Comment: What `kubeadm init` flags did you used to start your cluster? I'm seeing a potential mismatch in your pods subnets (`10.244.x.x` vs `192.168.x.x`). As per [Installing a pod network add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network), for Flannel to work correctly, you must pass `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` to `kubeadm init`.